# MUI DatePicker Error is shown, but still can submit

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have simple form with:

> Description, From Date, To Date

The problem is that I set `minDate(fromDate)` for To Date which is working if the user type 'TO DATE' that is smaller than 'FROM DATE' the DatePicker turns red, but I still can submit the form.
Is there a way to prevent this submit if the fields are in error state ?

[CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/formsubmitting-bsy4k1?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Please add a minimal reproducible code-snippet. And, you might have to check if [min](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_min.asp) attribute is added by the MUI DatePicker component. If not, you will have to do validations in form's onSubmit handler.

Comment: Sorry, code sandbox is added

Comment: The `form` isn't aware of the error in `DatePicker`. As long as there is a value, the form will be submitted. You should add validation that runs when submitting the form and validate if the values are the ones you want.